# When does a ball in a game of brick breaker never hit the remaining breaks?

Tags: puzzle, problem-solving

I have a block size 2N*2N and some squares are filled with bricks and some aren't. I have a ball that travels distance 1 in the x and y direction and bounces off with perpendicular direction if it hits a boundary or it hits a break. After what time will I know the remaining bricks will never be hit?

Comment: wording is not clear. could you elaborate?

Comment: When the ball is in the same place twice without hitting a brick.

Comment: ^What would this be in terms of time?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the boundaries of field are a square (which I assume is intended as the dimensions are listed as $2N*2N$), the ball will avoid the bricks indefinitely  if it, at some point, makes contact with all four walls without hitting a brick. Because the ball is only moving at 45 degree angles relative to the squares, after making one loop of the square, it will continue to do so forever.

*(this is similar to the reasoning of commenter @Cruncher.)*